When in Python is Multithreading faster than Asyncio?
I am wondering what is an example of a function in python that needs to be executed 1000 times, in which using a mulithreading approach would be faster than asyncio. The consensus from other answers seems to be that Asyncio is better for long block I/O tasks and Multithreading is better for short blocking I/O tasks.
But say we we had a function like:
def task():
    short_i/o_task() #10ms
    ten_second_cpu_task() #10s
    return

Because multithreading is not truly parallel in python, the collection of all 1000 ten_second_cpu_task() would take 10,000 seconds. I envision that because asyncio is also single threaded it would also take around 10,000 seconds. I am not understanding in what situations multithreading would be advantageous in python uses GIL and only one thread can run at a time.

I'm not sure this line of thinking is really productive.  Neither option is going to help CPU-bound tasks.  If you are CPU bound, you need to think about how you can get the computation done in C where the GIL can be released.  That's where numpy is a lifesaver.  I have a real-time system that processes man ymegabytes of telemetry per second using multithreading, because the real work is all done in numpy.

see my answer here where multithreading made numpy code almost 4 times faster on a 4 core cpu, you just offload calculations to C/C++ code and release the GIL, it is not as perfect as writing C/C++ code all the way, but the margin is sometimes acceptable.
